# how do I replace something from a output of PHP function?

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am trying make some changes in a php code -

Below line

`<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo $special; ?>"/>`

shows up like this in HTML

`<meta itemprop="price" content="£32.12"/>`

I need to remove this Pound("£") sign from the output. How can I use replace function in this code or there is some other way to do it.

Can someone advise?

Comment: So, did you try to `str_replace` it?

Comment: tried this - <meta itemprop="price content="<?php echo str_replace($special, '£','') ?>"/> it's not printing anything in this case.

Comment: £ = POUND,  € = EURO

Comment: [`str_replace( '£', '', $special )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: @PedroLobito: Sorry about that, I've updated this.

Comment: `echo trim($special, '£');`

Comment: well all theses answers are the ambulance at the bottom of the cliff - why not stop it being added in the first place

Comment: When in doubt about how a function works refer to the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php. Your usage should be in your question. As noted above you should probably correct the `$special` at the assignment level, unless you need it with pounds/euros later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php
//  REMOVES ONLY BRITISH CURRENCY: £ 
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo str_replace('£', '', $special); ?>"/>
```

OR this:

```
//  REMOVES CURRENCIES LIKE £, $ & € 
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo preg_replace('&(£|$|€)&', '', $special); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> how do I replace something from a output of PHP function?

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
<?php
$special = str_replace("£", "", $special);
?>
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php=$special;?>"/>
```

---

If you need to replace **multiple currencies**, you can use an `array`, i.e.:

```
<?php
$remove = array("£", "€", "$", "₹", "¥", "¢");
$special = str_replace($remove, "", $special);
?>
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php=$special;?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo str_replace("?", "", $special); ?>"/>
```

Comment: Can you expand a little on exactly what this does and how it might answer the OP?